# Powershell with WinForms - returning user input into a text box from a function

Tags: winforms, powershell, event-handling

I have set up a separate script for my form elements in powershell and am using dot-sourcing to link the two together. I am calling the text box function and this function should pass the user's input back to the original script but it doesn't.

```
---------- First Script - being used to call ---------- 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 


#---------- Overall Form Config ----------#
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "New Service Account"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"



#---------- Account Name Field ----------#

."C:\Temp\include.ps1"
formLabel -labLocW 10 -labLocH 20 -labSizeW 280 -labSizeH 30 -labText "Enter SVC Account Name (Do Not Include SVC_)"
$a = formTextBox -tboxLocW 10 -tboxLocH 50 -tboxSizeW 260 -tboxSizeH 30
$b = formTextBox -tboxLocW 10 -tboxLocH 100 -tboxSizeW 260 -tboxSizeH 30
#$ok = formOKBut -okLocW 100 -okLocH 120 -okSizeW 60 -okSizeH 30 -okText "OK"

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,120)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)


if($okbutton.Clicked){
    Write-Host $a

}

#---------- Show Form ----------#
$showForm = $form.ShowDialog() 


---------- Dot Script include ---------- 
function formTextBox($tboxLocW,$tboxLocH,$tboxSizeW,$tboxSizeH) {
    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($tboxLocW,$tboxLocH) 
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($tboxSizeW,$tboxSizeH) 
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)
    $output = $textBox.Text
    return $output
}
```

Comment: Just: `$OKButton.Add_Click({Write-Host $a})` ?

Comment: As an aside: your problem is unrelated to "dot-sourcing" another script (`. "C:\Temp\include.ps1"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your `formTextBox` function, you're trying to return the text of a text-box control *before the dialog has even been displayed*,** so that won't work.

Instead, return the *control* from the function, whose `.Text` property you can examine *after the dialog has been closed*:

```
function formTextBox($tboxLocW,$tboxLocH,$tboxSizeW,$tboxSizeH) {
    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($tboxLocW,$tboxLocH) 
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($tboxSizeW,$tboxSizeH) 
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)
    return $textBox # Return the text box itself (the object)
}

# ...

# Create the text box, add it to the form, and store it in variable $a.
$a = formTextBox -tboxLocW 10 -tboxLocH 50 -tboxSizeW 260 -tboxSizeH 30

# ...

# Invoke the dialog and act on how it was closed.
if ($form.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $textA = $a.Text  # Get the text box' text now.
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "OK clicked: text box `$a contains: $textA"
} else {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Dialog was closed without clicking OK."
}
```

---

Furthermore, **it looks like you were trying to react to the *event* of the OK button getting clicked** with the following code, which also won't work, because again, it executes *synchronously*, before the dialog is ever shown:

```
if($okbutton.Clicked){  # DOESN'T WORK - event delegate needed instead
    Write-Host $a    
}
```

Instead, **you need to set up an *event handler* (event delegate), which in PowerShell takes the form of `<control>.add_<event-name>({ ... })`**; in the case at hand, we want to react to the [`Click` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click):

```
$OKButton.add_Click({
    param([object] $sender, [System.EventArgs] $evtArgs)
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Button '$($sender.Text)' clicked."
})
```

The script block (`{ ... }`) will now be invoked *when the button is pressed*, whenever that occurs. The `param()` block declares the two arguments that are passed to your event delegate, although you can omit the declaration altogether if you don't need information about who originated the event (`$sender`) or the specifics of the event (`$evtArgs`), if any.

---

Note: To **determine a given `[System.Windows.Forms.Control]` type's  available events** as well as the specific `[System.EventArgs]` subclass that is passed, you can use something like
`New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button | Get-Member -MemberType Event`